# assigenment branching condition is too high robocop offense

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, robocopy

I have written and optimized the code like this

```
  def issues_json_for_v2(skip_avatar = false)
    @result_json ||= { results: [] }
    return if @result_set['issues'].empty?
    @result_set['total_entries'] = @result_set['meta']['total']
    fr_issues = @result_set['issues']
    user_hash = fr_results_hash(@result_set['users'])
    project_data = fr_results_hash(@result_set['projects'])
    if @suggest
      add_suggest_results_fr_issues(fr_issues, project_data)
    else
      fr_issues.each do |issue|
        p_data = project_data[issue['project_id']] if issue
        if issue && issue['owner_id']
          issue_json = append_fr_user_details_to_issue(safe_send(:fr_issue_json, issue, p_data), user_hash)
        else
          issue_json = safe_send(:fr_issue_json, issue, p_data)
        end
        @result_json[:results] << issue_json
      end
    end
    return @result_json[:results] if @size.nil?
    add_fr_prj_meta_data(fr_issues)
    @result_json[:results]
  end
```

Still I am getting

> Assignment Branch Condition size for issues_json_for_v2 is too high.

what optimization I can do while keeping the readability in the mind.

This is another method for which I am encountering this issue

```
  def project_json(project, id)
    human_display_id = project['key']
    title = sanitize_fr_data(project['name'])
    description = project['description'].blank? ? '' : project['description']
    description = sanitize_fr_data(description)
    prg = project['progress']
    percent_completion = (prg['done'] == 0) ? 0 : (prg['done'] * 100) / (prg['todo'] + prg['in_progress'] + prg['done'])
    current_time_zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING[current_user.time_zone]
    start_date = project['start_date'].nil? ? '--' : project['start_date'].in_time_zone(current_time_zone).strftime(date_time_format)
    end_date = project['end_date'].nil? ? '--' : project['end_date'].in_time_zone(current_time_zone).strftime(date_time_format)
    return { result_type: 'project', content: %{#{title} (#{human_display_id})}, path: fr_project_path(project['key']) } if @suggest
    {
      id: id,
      title: title,
      project_display_id: human_display_id,
      description: truncate(description, length: 250),
      owner: project['owner_id'],
      start_date: start_date,
      end_date: end_date,
      progress: {todo: project['progress']['todo'], in_progress: project['progress']['in_progress'], done: project['progress']['done']},
      percent_completion: percent_completion,
    }
  end
```

Comment: I'm not going to evaluate everything here, it does not seem like this is a question for Stackoverflow. What are you trying to achieve with this code and what are the inputs and desired outputs? There's far too much going on here and you need to split out these methods. Instance variables should be organised in initialize and it seems like this method is doing enough processing to warrant its own class... maybe.

Comment: Why are you setting a new key in the hash when it can be derived from a nested key in the same hash? `@result_set['total_entries']` is not even used in the method you are setting it. Is `fr_results_hash` a method that transforms the instance variables? It can probably be optimised. What is `add_suggest_results_fr_issues` doing and how does it effect the code. Does it mutate the object fr_issues is pointing to, somehow?

Comment: I would really start by writing documentation - create a one liner description and if you can't do that without using `and` or `or` the method is doing to much. And I would say yes this code absolutely should be extracted out into something like a serializer.

Comment: Almost couldn't stand the irony of _"what optimization I can do while keeping the readability"_ - what readability? But in all seriousness, both these methods are doing way too much and need to be broken down into smaller parts so that each small method can be tested in isolation. Otherwise there are too many different permutations to test. Also, I couldn't work out what would change if I called the first method with `skip_avatar` set to `true` instead of using the default.

Answer (score 0):

ABC metrics are there specifically to help with readability. As a general rule, if you hit the ABC limit, the code is likely to be a lot less readable than you would think because the method is simply doing too much.

I would suggest:

- think about how many different ways there are through the method (branches)
- think about how you would go about testing all of those branches, or at least executing every code path

If you're struggling to figure out what that would really take, then you have a good idea about what the ABC metric is pointing out.

To refactor your code, I would:

- extract `@result_json` to be behind an accessor method that will ensure it is always created, then in your issues method call result_json instead of `@result_json`

```
def result_json
  @result_json ||= { results: [] }
end
```

- separate out your logic dealing with `@result_set` - consider creating a class that wraps result set and provides appropriate accessors, e.g.

```
class ResultSet
  def initialize(hsh)
    @hsh = hsh
  end

  def total_entries
    @hsh['meta']['total']
  end

  def issues
    @hsh['issues']
  end

  def users
    # obviously... you need the fr_results_hash method available here too
    @user_hash ||= fr_results_hash(@hsh['users'])
  end

  def project_data
    @project_data ||= fr_results_hash(@hsh['projects'])
  end
end
```

then this allows you to use this in your method like `result_set = ResultSet.new(@result_set)` and call directly to those instance methods like `result_set.project_data` instead of creating a local variable to hold each of those data.

- Assuming that `@result_set['issues']` is an Array, calling `.compact` on the array (`fr_issues.compact.each do |issue|`) will remove all of the `nil` values from the array, which is I think what you're guarding against when checking `if issue` in your `fr_issues.each` block. This means that you can remove those conditions because they can't happen.

More generally, there is a very high use of `@variables` in that method. That makes the method very hard to understand without context. Consider if those really should be instance methods or should they be scoped to within the method itself.

Your second method is having issues because of the overuse of ternary operations and needing to assign those to variables in the method. Creating some helper methods will assist, such as instead of:

```
start_date = project['start_date'].nil? ? '--' : project['start_date'].in_time_zone(current_time_zone).strftime(date_time_format)
end_date = project['end_date'].nil? ? '--' : project['end_date'].in_time_zone(current_time_zone).strftime(date_time_format)
```

have:

```
def format_date(value)
  value.nil? ? '--' : value.in_time_zone(current_time_zone).strftime(date_time_format)
end
```

then in your method, just use `format_date(project['start_date'])` and `format_date(project['end_date'])`. Because there is no complexity with calling those, just call them directly in your final hash instead of assigning them to a variable.
Similarly, adding a method `def project_completion_percent(progress)` then calling `project_completion_percent(project['progress'])` directly in your return hash will get rid of 2 assignments and a branch. Another idea... a method to format your `description` will mean that you can get rid of 2 lines of code from the method, 2 assignments and a branch.

There are plenty more optimisations, but hopefully that gives enough pointers